# Getting the right day of the week (Java Calendar)

Tags: java, calendar

I manage some dates in my own date classes. I want to create a method like this in my date:

```
int getWeekdayIndex()
```

right now it lookes something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.set(year, month+1, day); // data of this date
int weekdayIndex = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
return weekdayIndex;
```

I know DAY_OF_WEEK returns 1(Sunday) to 7(Saturday), but if I test this method with

2014-01-06 I get index 5 (suppost to be 2)

2014-01-07 I get index 6 (suppost to be 3)

(I live in Berlin UTC+01:00 - if it matters)

Comment: What exactly are you inputting when you say "I test this method with"?

Comment: can you pls post your code so it is clea how variables year, month and day are populated, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
cal.set(year, month-1, day); // data of this date
```

Do note the `month-1` part instead of `month+1`.

Assuming that month's value is:

```
1 for Jan
2 for Feb
3 for Mar
...
```

Answer (score 1):

What is `month` in your scenario?  If it's `0` for "January", you are adding `1` when calling the [`set` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29).  But months in Java are zero-based, so you're setting "February", and February 6th, 2014 is a Thursday (5), and February 7th, 2014 is a Friday (6).

> month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

Try changing

```
cal.set(year, month+1, day);
```

to

```
cal.set(year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 has convenient methods for such work.

The [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class offers a [`dayOfWeek`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#dayOfWeek%28%29) method. From that you can derive either the localized name of the day, and to your needs, the number. Joda-Time counts days using the international standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), where Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7.

Example code…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

DateTimeZone berlinTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Berlin" );

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2013, DateTimeConstants.DECEMBER, 13, 14, 15, 16, berlinTimeZone );
String dayOfWeekAsText = dateTime.dayOfWeek().getAsText( Locale.GERMANY );
int dayOfWeekAsNumber = dateTime.dayOfWeek().get();

System.out.println( "dayOfWeekAsText: " + dayOfWeekAsText );
System.out.println( "dayOfWeekAsNumber: " + dayOfWeekAsNumber );
```

When run…

```
dayOfWeekAsText: Freitag
dayOfWeekAsNumber: 5
```

Easy to jump to another month.

```java
DateTime previousMonthDateTime = dateTime.minusMonths( 1 );
DateTime nextMonthDateTime = dateTime.plusMonths( 1 );
```